# Opening dialog from another dialog with Angular Material and Safari

Tags: angular, safari, angular-material, angular-material2, angular5

Please take a look at the following app:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qxhep

I'm trying to open a dialog from within another dialog. The shared example works fine in Chrome but it doesn't work in Safari.

If you check the two console.log() statements in safari the result looks different:

**Safari**

First dialog info:

```
MatDialogRef {_overlayRef: OverlayRef, _containerInstance: MatDialogContainer, id: "dialog1", disableClose: false, _afterOpen: Subject, …}
```

Second dialog info:

```
MatDialogRef {_overlayRef: OverlayRef, _containerInstance: MatDialogContainer, id: "dialog1", disableClose: false, _afterOpen: Subject, …}
```

**Chrome**

First dialog info:

```
MatDialogRef {_overlayRef: OverlayRef, _containerInstance: MatDialogContainer, id: "dialog1", disableClose: false, _afterOpen: Subject, …}
```

Second dialog info:

```
MatDialogRef {_overlayRef: OverlayRef, _containerInstance: MatDialogContainer, id: "dialog2", disableClose: false, _afterOpen: Subject, …}
```

Notice that for Chrome the 'id' parameter passed to the dialogs is properly picked up, for Safari I don't get the same behaviour and therefore Safari does not open the second dialog panel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because since Safari has no native support for the Web Animations API, you have to install `web-animations-js`. The GIF below shows you how to install a dependency on Stackblitz:

[image: How to install a dependency on Stackblitz]

*Sorry if the quality if a bit blurry*

And uncomment this line from `polyfills.ts`:

```ts
/** ALL Firefox browsers require the following to support `@angular/animation`. **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // <- Uncomment this line
```

Here's the [support status for Web Animations API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation).

Lastly, please do not use unpkg for the theming as it will get the CSS from the latest `master` and may introduce breaking changes. Instead, use it in `styles.css` as follows:

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs-so)

Comment: Thanks @Edric - was this something you had experience with before? How did you figure it out?

Comment: That's because the documentation site had a `web-animations-js` import as seen [here](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/66f7a617b6ad5844014a775a74a35896d8ddbdb8/src/index.html#L31) and there was a line on `polyfills.ts` with the comment saying as in above

Comment: It's also in [`getting-started.md`](https://material2-docs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/getting-started#step-2-animations)